# Почему не работает scrollbar для таблицы?

Tags: html, css, table

Хочу сделать `scrollbar` для таблицы но почему-то не получается. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```css
table#messages {
  width: 490px;
  height: 260px;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

```html
<table id="messages">
  <tr class="mess_hide">
    <td class="time"></td>
    <td class="name"></td>
    <td class="message"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А вы уверены в правильности написания ваших правил css? Попробуйте убрать table перед #messages

Comment: @Klimenkomud Я пробовал и так, и просто `table`, не помогает.

Comment: Попробуйте не overflow-y: auto, а overflow-y: scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте, Максим. Можно просто обернуть таблицу в дополнительный контейнер с фиксированной высотой у которого `overflow-y: auto`.

```css
.scroller {
  width: 490px;
  height: 260px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
table#messages {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr><tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr><tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time">text</td>
      <td class="name">text</td>
      <td class="message">text</td>
    </tr>
    
    
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает, но только когда количество строк превышает высоту контейнера, а до этого он вообще практически не виден(полоска на 100% ширины и 5-10px высоты).Как сделать так что бы скрол был даже тогда, когда  в таблицу ничего не введено?

Comment: Исправил, указав максимальные высоты `.scroller-у` и таблице)